# Maximizing speed on hybrid drive

Tags: 12.04, boot, hard-drive, ssd

I have a hybrid drive (ST750LX003 to be exact), is 750 GB including an 8 GB SSD. I currently have Ubuntu 12.04 installed, and I recently had a dual-boot installed with Windows 8. The problem is, Win8 booted up much faster than Ubuntu (10-15 seconds vs. 25-30 seconds). I had a suspicion that Windows was stealing the SSD space, so I uninstalled it, and combined the partition with my Ubuntu partition. So far, Ubuntu isn't booting any faster.

Also, I know Windows 8 has the hibernation/shutdown feature, but that wasn't working anyways. (i.e. when I selected the power button, it didn't shut down. I had to restart.)

Is it possible to tell what files are stored on the SSD part of the drive?

Edit: I do have several partitions on my drive. Is it possible that the SSD space only maps to space in a particular partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to tell what files are in the SSD cache.  I ran the hybrid drive at a previous job on Win7 and I know it did make a difference in boot time.  Supposedly the drive firmware is supposed to figure out what files are most frequently used and/or used to boot and put them in cache.  It would be quite a destructive experiment but I wonder if a full format would clean out the cache?

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather not do a re-format... Do you know if it works across partitions?